# Why does only the first CSS class of my project working and not the rest

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using React with CSS and for some reason, my CSS doesn't show up. Let me demonstrate.

I have my "App.js" with this code:

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
return(
    <div>
      <p className="wow">hhh</p>
      <p className="pow">hhh</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And I have my App.css with this code:

```
.wow {
  color: blue;
};

.pow {
  color: red;
};
```

When I look in my browser only the first class is working and the letters are blue but not the second one or any other after. If I create a new component and import a CSS document to it as I did in the previous one the same thing will happen, the first CSS class will work and that's all after that non of the classes work.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be due to the trailing semicolon `;` in your CSS? I think that's obsolete but potentially messing it up.

Comment: You are a genius!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's due to the following semi-colon after your first class in App.css. CSS does not support semi-colons after selectors.

```
.wow {
   color: blue;
}

.pow {
   color: red;
}
```